# How to create a dictionary with a list of list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary with a list as the keys and a list of lists as my values.

I tried the following code below but it has just took the last 3 values of my grades list. I'm stuck on how I should specify my list of lists to properly loop over each name.

```
grades = [[100, 90, 80], [88, 99, 111], [45, 56, 67], [59, 61, 67], [73, 79, 83], [89, 97, 101]]
names = ['Jerry', 'Terry', 'Larry', 'Harry', 'Mary', 'Carry']

test3 = {k:row for row in grades2 for k in names}
print(test3)

Out: {'Jerry': [89, 97, 101], 'Terry': [89, 97, 101], 'Larry': [89, 97, 101], 'Harry': [89, 97, 101], 'Mary': [89, 97, 101], 'Carry': [89, 97, 101]}
```

My expected outcome would be `{name:[list of grades],name:[list of grades]...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using nested loops (which produces the Cartesian product of `names` and `grades`) when you should be iterating the `names` and `grades` lists in parallel, which you can do using `zip`:

```
test3 = {k : row for k, row in zip(names, grades)}

print(test3)
```

Output:

```
{'Jerry': [100, 90, 80], 'Terry': [88, 99, 111], 'Larry': [45, 56, 67], 'Harry': [59, 61, 67], 'Mary': [73, 79, 83], 'Carry': [89, 97, 101]}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {name:grade for name, grade in zip(names, grades)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` to iterate the names and grades in parallel, and then pass that to the `dict` constructor, which among other things can make a dictionary from an iterable of keys and values.

```
test3 = dict(zip(names, grades))
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for loops!

```
test3 = dict(zip(names, [x for x in grades]))
Out: {'Jerry': [100, 90, 80],
      'Terry': [88, 99, 111],
      'Larry': [45, 56, 67],
      'Harry': [59, 61, 67],
      'Mary': [73, 79, 83],
      'Carry': [89, 97, 101]}
```